# ContentFlow plugin: Changing size of non-active elements

Tags: javascript, plugins

For anyone that's used the javascript plugin "ContentFlow" (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/), do you have any idea how to change the size of the NON-ACTIVE elements? It seems that they're always half the height of the center image, but I'd like to make it something closer to 75% of the height.

I've been digging through the JS source code, but I can't seem to pinpoint the place where I adjust the size. Every time I adjust a value, it resizes all of the elements, including the active center image.

Please note, my "visibleItems" property is set to 1, as I only need to display one image on either side of the center image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Gallery addon. There is a calcSize function in the addon JS that may help you calculate the size you want.